# Time Stamp into sentences

Tags: linux, bash

Would like to have a tool to take a time stamp and turn it into a half sentence.

Sample Time Stamp:

> 03/25/2016 11:33:16 AM

Sample Output:

> at 11:33 AM on 3/25.

Additionally, how would can I account for 2 possible time stamps.

Sample2

```
./TimeStampTool.sh 03/25/2016 11:32:05 AM 03/25/2016 11:33:16 AM
```

Sample2 Output:

> between 11:32 and 11:33 AM on 3/25.

Script so far

```
#!/bin/bash <br/>
if [ -n $4 ] <br/>
echo "between '$2 $3' and '$5 $6' on '$1'." <br/>
elif <br/>
echo "at '$2 $3' on '$1'." <br/>
exit
```

Comment: Doesn't the `date` command do everything you need? It can parse an input timestamp, and it can format the output in a variety of ways.

Comment: I am pasting time-stamps from a other logs.

Comment: So? What difference does it make where you get them? The `date` command can parse most common date and time formats.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar, SO is for questions, not for requests.

Comment: I am just trying to make my life easier. You didn't have to answer my requestion, someone will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stamp to different format, single line bash script

```
date -d "$1" +'at %T on %m/%d'
```

"between" script

```
$ sh tst.sh '03/25/2016 11:32:05 AM' '03/25/2016 11:33:16 AM'
between 11:32:05 and 11:33:16 on on 03/25
$ more tst.sh 

t1=`date -d "$1" +'%T'`
t2=`date -d "$2" +'%T'`

day=`date -d "$1" +'on %m/%d'`

echo "between $t1 and $t2 on $day"
```

Note the script assumes the days of the timestamps are the same and does not detect which stamp is first

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to this, and edit for Your further needs:

```
   | sed -r -e 's/^[^ ]+ /at /g' -e 's/:.. / /g'
```

Regex is not most efficient, but You can tune it quickly.